# Script works in Anaconda Prompt but not via Command Line

Tags: python

I am unable to run a python script in the command line, and this script works great in Jupyter Notebook and via Anaconda Prompt. This appears to be an issue importing the ssl module during initialization of another module I am importing (mygeotab).

I have googled the error and done as much as I can to diagnose the most common cause which appears to be PATH issues.

I have already diagnosed the PATH to a point, and have added the location of the /lib/ and python.exe to the environment variables. Also, during testing I began my script with the below to protect myself from path issues and printed the path before and after the 'append', which did not have an impact on the problem.

```
import sys
print(sys.path)

sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\xxxxxx\\Python Scripts')
sys.path.append('C:\\Anaconda3\\python37.zip')
sys.path.append('C:\\Anaconda3\\DLLs')
sys.path.append('C:\\Anaconda3\\lib')
sys.path.append('C:\\Anaconda3')
sys.path.append('C:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages')
sys.path.append('C:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32')
sys.path.append('C:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib')
sys.path.append('C:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin')
sys.path.append('C:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions')
sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\xxxxxx\\.ipython')
sys.path.append('C:\\Anaconda3\\Lib')
sys.path.append('C:\\Anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages')

print(sys.path)
```

```
import mygeotab
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc as py
from mygeotab.ext import feed
import sqlalchemy
from time import sleep
```

However, when I attempt to run the script via the standard command line, I get the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PYTHON_GEOTAB_TRIP_FEED.py", line 33, in <module>
    import mygeotab
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mygeotab\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .api import Credentials
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mygeotab\api.py", line 14, in <module>
    import ssl
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 98, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

The mygeotab module and ssl.py are both in the locations designated in the Traceback. '_ssl' is the only reference I can not seem to diagnose. Again, this works fine in both Notebook and Anaconda Prompt.

Any ideas?

- Windows Server 2008 R2
- Anaconda 2019.07 x64
- Python 3.7.3 x64

Comment: How are you calling the script? What version(s) of Python are you using? Welcome to Stack Overflow btw! You can [edit] your post.

Comment: Thanks. Updated my OS, anaconda, and python versions above. Excited to get more internet points so I can contribute more, thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Did you download using anaconda prompt or command line pip? The location of the package may not be known to the system in which case you need to update your path and not just do sys.path.append

Comment: Open up command line and make sure you are in your C: directory. Type pip list and tell me if mygeotab is there.

Comment: Downloaded via Anaconda prompt I believe. Asking C:\ for pip list in the command prompt gives me an
c:\>pip list
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Also, I did add the /lib/ and /site-packages/ directories to the environment variable path, the sys.append was an attempt at a band-aid fix when that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This was solved for me by installing a separate instance of Python 3.7, moving the PATH references and other pointers. I installed pip, mygeotab, and the other packages into the native Python 3.7 instance. It just appears you can't use the one baked into anaconda the way I thought. Thanks for the help everyone.